# Phase portraits of gradient systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Can a gradient system such as

x' =  $\frac{dH}{dx}$

y' = $\frac{dH}{dy}$

where H $\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$

have a focus on a critical point? 
If so, could anyone give me a example?

I know that the linear part of a gradient system cannot have a focus on a critical point, but does it mean that the non-linear system cannot have a critical point either? For instance, is it possible that the linear system has a node on the origin but the non-linear system has a focus?

Comment: Okay, let's do the reasoning here. 1) In what cases non-linear system has focus equilibrium? Is there link between type of equilibrium of nonlinear and linearized system?  2) How Jacobi matrix of this system is different from any other Jacobi matrix? Does it have special structure? Does this structure somehow influences eigenvalues of the Jacobi matrix? I think that answering both these questions will help you.